# Appending Text to Div Extends Div Beyond Initial CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've created a basic CSS Grid and had everything positioned where I wanted it. When I run my JS (appends info from an API call to a div), the div's dimension push beyond the borders of the viewport. Is there a way to prevent the overall body element from changing and just have the div dynamically increase height?

pics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZPch.jpg

I've tried so many different things and can't seem to figure this out. My fallback will be to just overwrite the div rather than append to it. Code is below.

```js
//Set initial latitute and longitude variables, to be used later
var lat = 0;
var long = 0;

//Google Geocode API to find the latitude and longitude of the txtAddress
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
  var userInput = $("#txtAddress").val();
  //trim the user input to the form needed for the api
  var userSearchTerm = userInput.split(' ').join('+');

  //call the google geocode api
  var queryURLGeocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + userSearchTerm + "&key=AIzaSyCSAYHZn9fz13c3bsl_RcS13HJu8wDJXCU"
  $.ajax({
      url: queryURLGeocode,
      method: "GET"
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      //Set latitude and longitude from the returned object
      lat = response.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      //limit decimal points to 4 (xx.xxxx) - form needed for hiking api
      lat = lat.toFixed(4);

      long = response.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      long = long.toFixed(4);

      //Call the hiking project api
      var queryURL = "https://www.hikingproject.com/data/get-trails?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long + "&maxDistance=10&key=200206461-4fa8ac1aa85295888ce833cca1b5929f"

      $.ajax({
          url: queryURL,
          method: "GET"
        })
        .done(function(response) {
          // loop through the response trails and add info to the site
          for (i = 0; i < response.trails.length; i++) {
            var contentDivTitle = $("<div> class='newTrailTitle'");
            var contentDivMain = $("<div> class='newTrailDescription'");
            contentDivTitle.text("Name: " + response.trails[i].name + "     Location: " + response.trails[i].location);
            contentDivMain.text("Summary: " + response.trails[i].summary);
            $("#search-results").append(contentDivTitle);
            $("#search-results").append(contentDivMain);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1,
h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1px;
}

h1 {
  /* automatically changes lowercase to uppercase text; */
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

sub {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 800px 500px 200px 50px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.container>div:nth-child(1n) {
  background-color: black;
}

.container>div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container>div:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container>div:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container>div:nth-child(5n) {
  background-color: green;
}

label {
  color: white;
}

#main {
  background-image: url("assets/images/etienne-bosiger-367964.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#au,
#cr {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#groupPic {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="title">

        <h1>kairns<sub>&reg;</sub></h1>
        <h3>"find your trail"</h3>
        <div class="search-div">
          <label for="txtAddress">Enter Address: </label>
          <input type="text" name="txtAddress" id="txtAddress">
          <button type="button" id="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>



    <div class="search-results" id="search-results">2</div>

    <div>
      <p id="au">About Us</p>
      <img id="groupPic" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="placeholder image">
      <p id="cr">Copyright 2018.</p>
    </div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>
      <p>Powered by
        <a href="https://developers.google.com/maps/">Google Maps</a>,
        <a href="https://openweathermap.org/api">Open Weather Map</a>, and <a href="https://www.hikingproject.com/data">Hiking Project</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- custom javaScript -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src='assets/javascript/logic.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Be aware that you have a syntax error in the grid container: `grid-template-columns: 1000px, auto;` There should be no comma. Once you make that adjustment, the container becomes two columns and the entire layout changes. Not sure this addresses your main problem, but you should settle that issue first.

Comment: Add `overflow: auto` to the blue container (`#search-results`). Is that what you're after?

Comment: @Michael_B , thanks I've edited to remove the "1000px, ". So it should all appear as one column now... 

`#search-results { overflow: auto; }`

that definitely helps! but is there a way to do it vertically instead of horizontally (right now, my blue div gets a scroll bar added to it)

Comment: Try this: Add `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to `#search-results`.

Comment: @Michael_B , you're BRILLIANT! TY, man! 
you have no idea how long I've been trying to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in-flow children of the `#search-results` element will align vertically if you apply:

```
#search-results {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
```